# how to time series log line data

Tags: grafana-loki

```
2022-06-30 13:10:02 
time=1656583802.07378, Composite=35.85, Packageid0=44.0, Core0=41.0, Core1=39.0, Core2=40.0, Core3=39.0, Core4=40.0, Core5=44.0, Core6=40.0, Core7=40.0, 
2022-06-30 13:05:01 
time=1656583501.9661329, Composite=35.85, Packageid0=43.0, Core0=43.0, Core1=39.0, Core2=40.0, Core3=39.0, Core4=40.0, Core5=40.0, Core6=40.0, Core7=40.0, 
2022-06-30 13:00:01 
time=1656583201.8478107, Composite=35.85, Packageid0=42.0, Core0=42.0, Core1=39.0, Core2=39.0, Core3=39.0, Core4=39.0, Core5=40.0, Core6=41.0, Core7=39.0, 
2022-06-30 12:55:01 
time=1656582901.7286851, Composite=35.85, Packageid0=41.0, Core0=41.0, Core1=39.0, Core2=40.0, Core3=40.0, Core4=39.0, Core5=40.0, Core6=40.0, Core7=39.0
```

how can i map this to graph / time series

[sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GhaS.png)

**NOTE**: i am beginner in grafana

**DATA SOURCE**: python script running every 5m

Comment: what have you tried so far and didn't work?

Comment: I switched to mysql ... it worked easily with same data ...